# NDK- Build command failed. Error while executing process android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

Hi there are many questions asked about this issue but couldn't ressolve mine. So posted my error, If someone can guide me to specific error. Thanks

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\Spartan_Base\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\android\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\android\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=D:/android/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\android\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\release\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
Android NDK: D:\android\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'box2D' in import path    
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?    
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:    
Android NDK:         
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\Spartan_Base\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\android\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\android\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=D:/android/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\android\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: D:\android\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'box2D' in import path    
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?    
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:    
Android NDK:         
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **Android.mk** has a line

```
$(call import-module, box2D)
```

but you did not add the path to **box2D/Android.mk** to **NDK_MODULE_PATH**.

See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html for explanations.

If you download https://github.com/mcxiaoke/box2d-ndk to **D:\Downloads\box2D**, you can add line

```
NDK_MODULE_PATH += D:/Downloads/box2D/jni
```

to `D:\android\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk`

Comment: Actualy this project is done by my ex-coleague and I cannot find box2d in my project.

Comment: box2d is probably not part of the project. import-module typically is used for external components.

Comment: may I remove this line or I have to add module can you explain it please.

Comment: You can try to remove this imported, but most likely you will get unresolved references and headers. You can try this Android port for box2d instead: https://github.com/mcxiaoke/box2d-ndk

Comment: http://www.cnblogs.com/mcxiaoke/archive/2012/07/21/build-box2d-with-ndk-for-android.html

Comment: Above link is throwing 404

Comment: The discussion is gone (have your tried the archive?) but the sources are available on GitHub

Comment: should I copy box2D folder in my project and give its path to $(call import-module, box2D)? Or assign path to box2d's Android.mk?

Comment: As explained in the cited document, it does not matter where you put box2d on your computer. Only make sure that the path of its **Android.mk** is on **NDK_MODULE_PATH**.

Comment: Thanks very very much for help. It solved issue for this module but I have 3 three modules in Android.mk same as this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292725/android-ndk-are-you-sure-your-ndk-module-path-variable-is-properly-defined?rq=1

Comment: how should I fix all modules

Comment: how your problem solved of box2D module? i have downloaded and added its Android.mk file path as NDK_MODULE_PATH in my project's Android.mk file but stil its not finding that module?? i have cocos2dx & core modules same issues like you...if you solved it then please share it @Sohail Khan

Comment: @natiqjavid note that it is "too late" to modify NDK_MODULE_PATH in **Android.mk**. You can set it on **ndk-build** command line, or in the **Application.mk** file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know , if this is the right solution, but my issue got fixed after I opened Android.mk file from JNI folder and removed some empty lines that were there in the beginning of the file